# Wait till all the Qt concurrent threads finished

Tags: multithreading, qt, qtconcurrent

I am running 5 threads as below

```
for(int i=0; i< 5 ; i++
{
   QtConcurrent::run()
}
```

I want to wait here till all the threads get finished.

```
void QFutureSynchronizer::waitForFinished ()  is hanging my main GUI.
```

So I want to use some thing like this QEventLoop::exec();

But how to exit out of this exec() once all the results available?

Edited:
  - I did some thing like this, that works for me

```
constructor()
{
   m_noOfThreadsFinished = 0;
   m_totalThreads = 5;

    for(int i=0; i< 5 ; i++
    {
       QFuture<void> l_future =  QtConcurrent::run();
       QPointer< QFutureWatcher<void> >  l_futurewatcher = new  QFutureWatcher<void>();
        connect(l_futurewatcher, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(FinishedThread()) );
        l_futurewatcher->setFuture(l_future);    
    }

    if(eventLoop != NUL)
          delete eventLoop;
    eventLoop = new QEventLoop(); // QPointer<QEventLoop> eventLoop; is class member

     //start event loop here, so that GUI wont block
     eventLoop->ecec(); 

    //do things after all threads finished
}

void FinishedThread() //slot 
{
    QFutureWatcher<void>* l_futurewatcher = static_cast< QFutureWatcher<void>* > (sender());
    l_futurewatcher->deleteLater();

   if( (++m_noOfThreadsFinished == m_totalThreads) && !m_processCancelled)
   {
        emit finishedreading();
   }
}

void FinishedAllThreads() //slot for finishedreading 
{
    killLocalEventLoop();
}

void killLocalEventLoop()
{
  //QPointer automatically make eventLoop to NULL, when it got deleted 
  eventLoop->quit();
  eventLoop->deleteLater();
}
```

**NOTE :**  you people can ask why cann't I do the things in FinishedThread() slot when I get to know all threads are finished, project I am working in  forcing me to do the things in constructor only when all threads finished(This may not be situation for you then you can do things in FinishedThread() slot).

Comment: How about start creating and wainting threads finished at separate thread with own(non-GUI) event loop?

Comment: I dont want to use low level threads here, I just looking for how can I come out of exec() once I done with all the threads ??

Comment: How about using signal & slots?

Comment: Why can't you use `QFutureWatcher`?

Comment: I found that QFutureWatcher hangs my main gui - at least if it is inside a button click handler. (The title bar had "(Not responding" on it).  I used a progress dialog to hide this, but that isn't appropriate in all cases.

Comment: I can not use QFutureWatcher @m.s.    big story to write .

Comment: @MichaelVincent  I am having a same problem

Comment: @Durga do you have a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which reproduces the issue you have with `QFutureWatcher`?

Comment: @m.s.  if you remove the progress dialog from the tutorial here: http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_QtConcurrent_QFutureWatcher_QProgressDialog_map.php you will see the problem with the application not responding when using QFutureWatcher inside a button click.

Comment: @Durga I haven't treid it, but I wonder if one solution would be to move the calling code into another non-gui thread, then call the 5 threads from that thread.  A single signal back to the gui from the intermediate thread could be sent when all other threads are complete.

Comment: @MichaelVincent why would one use `waitForFinished`? of course this will block the GUI. `QFutureWatcher` provides a `finished`signal, use this!

Answer (score 2):

The solution is quite simple: don't ever use any `waitForXxx` methods in Qt. They are never necessary.

Instead, you should be connecting to the `QFutureWatcher::finished()` signal. See, for example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30983853/1329652).

> For some other reason I can not use QFutureWatcher() to get to know all the finished results.

There's no such reason.